# Wrapping Lyx Graphic

Tags: graphics, lyx, diagrams, wrap

I'm very new to this whole LaTeX system, but I love the typesetting, it looks so much better than Word, but i'm currently preparing an article with multiple columns using a \start{multicols} script i found on the net, but i'm having huge difficulty inserting an image so it wraps around the text. It kind of works for the first column but then it doesn't see the rest of the text. I tried the setting for the 'float image wrap' to right, left, inner, outer, overhang but they don't make much of a difference.

Is there any way to get around this?

(I have enclosed a picture, sorry about the woeful Adobe Acrobat snapshot quality...)

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: it would be great if you could provide the code you wrote as a MWE. This would make it much easier for us to figure out where your problem is located :)

Comment: If you're still wondering about this: Your image is too wide to fit in the allocated space. Do you want the image to take up the entire column width, or just half as indicated by your image?